# Why vuex-orm returns null in relationship field?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I followed the guide of [Defining Relationships](https://vuex-orm.github.io/vuex-orm/guide/relationships/defining-relationships.html) in Vuex ORM.

I did everything like the guide, so why I get null value in category field in Article Model?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-v1beu?fontsize=14)

This is how I defining my models (category on article is: hasOne/belongTo):

```
export class Category extends Model {
  static entity = "categories";

  static primaryKey = "_id";

  static fields() {
    return {
      _id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.attr("")
    };
  }
}


export class Article extends Model {
  static entity = "articles";

  static primaryKey = "_id";

  static fields() {
    return {
      _id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.attr(""),
      category: this.hasOne(Category, "_id")
    };
  }
}
```

Config Vuex-orm with vuex in `main.js`:

```
import VuexORM from "@vuex-orm/core";
import { Article, Category } from "./models";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const database = new VuexORM.Database();

const Articles = {
  namespaced: true,

  actions: {
    test() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

const Categories = {
  namespaced: true,

  actions: {
    test() {
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
};

database.register(Article, Articles);
database.register(Category, Categories);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [VuexORM.install(database)]
});
```

Inside app component I have the data that I insert to vuex and get the values like so:

```
 const articleData = [
      {
        _id: "6ce9bae00000000000000000",
        name: "article-1",
        category: "5ce9acd00000000000000000"
      }
    ];
    const categoryData = [
      { _id: "5ce9acd00000000000000000", name: "category-1" }
    ];

    const x = await Article.insertOrUpdate({ data: articleData });
    const y = await Category.insertOrUpdate({ data: categoryData });

    const a = Article.query()
      .with("category")
      .first();

    console.log({ a });
    console.log({ type: a.category });
    console.log("why a.category is null???");
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the relationship between an article and a category is likely to be a one to many relationship however the issue with your code is the way you are defining the model and inserting data.

In your example you are attempting to provide a foreign key on the relationship target (I am an article and I know the category id I belong to). This kind of relationship is a one-to-one inverse relationship in Vuex-ORM.

In order to get your expected behavior, change your `Article` model as follows:

```
export class Article extends Model {
  static entity = "articles";

  static primaryKey = "_id";

  static fields() {
    return {
      _id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.attr(""),
      category_id: this.attr(""),
      category: this.belongsTo(Category, "category_id")
    };
  }
}
```

Note that you are explicitly defining a `category_id` as a separate field on the Article model rather than pointing to the id field on the Category model. This is the same pattern in all Vuex-ORM relationships. The `category` field stores the resolved relationship target object, so you destination category object. This is filled in by Vuex-ORM after you query using `.with(Category)` and should not be included in the data you insert.

Although it wouldn't make much sense, to fix your original example and use a standard one-to-one define your model as follows:

```
export class Article extends Model {
  static entity = "articles";

  static primaryKey = "_id";

  static fields() {
    return {
      _id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.attr(""),
      category: this.hasOne(Category, "article_id")
    };
  }
}

export class Category extends Model {
  static entity = "categories";

  static primaryKey = "_id";

  static fields() {
    return {
      _id: this.attr(null),
      name: this.attr(""),
      article_id: this.attr(null),
    };
  }
}
```

And provide an article_id in the data you pass to `Article.insertOrUpdate`.